# Wrong Image on iOS 8 Selected UISegmenetedControl Press

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegmentedControl with 2 buttons.  I set their background images for `.Normal`, `.Selected`, and `.Highlighted`.  Everything works perfectly in iOS 7, but only almost perfectly in iOS8.  When you use the button normally and only tap the button that is not selected everything works. But for some reason in iOS 8 when you press the already selected button you get a gray background instead of the selected image.  Below are the images to show what i mean.

**Right side selected**

[image: Regular Tabs, with one selected]

**Left Side Tapped on Non Selected Tab**

[image]

**Right Side Tapped with Right Side Selected**

[image]

I have already tried a few things, like setting backgroundColor to clear, or seeing if there is a state I was missing but I can't seem to find a solution.

Thanks for any suggestions.

As requested here is the code:

```
self.feedTypeButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.imageWithColor(UIColor(hex: "#cee4ee")).resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsZero), forState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
self.feedTypeButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.imageWithColor(Colors.blue).resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsZero), forState: .Selected, barMetrics: .Default)
self.feedTypeButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.imageWithColor(Colors.mediumBlue).resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsZero), forState: .Highlighted, barMetrics: .Default)

var dividerImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(Colors.blue, size: CGSize(width: 1, height: 28)).resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsZero)
self.feedTypeButton.setDividerImage(dividerImage, forLeftSegmentState: .Selected, rightSegmentState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
self.feedTypeButton.setDividerImage(dividerImage, forLeftSegmentState: .Normal, rightSegmentState: .Selected, barMetrics: .Default)
self.feedTypeButton.setDividerImage(dividerImage, forLeftSegmentState: .Normal, rightSegmentState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)


self.feedTypeButton.setTitleTextAttributes([ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: Colors.gray, NSFontAttributeName: UI.regularFontOfSize(13) ], forState: .Normal)
self.feedTypeButton.setTitleTextAttributes([ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: Colors.white, NSFontAttributeName: UI.boldFontOfSize(15)], forState: .Selected)
self.feedTypeButton.setTitleTextAttributes([ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: Colors.white ], forState: .Highlighted)
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: I am also finding this. Did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the segment turns grey on selecting an already selected segment is because the segmented control is missing the state for selected and highlighted at the same time.

In your case, to fix the problem just call:

```
self.feedTypeButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.imageWithColor(Colors.mediumBlue).resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsZero), forState:.Selected | .Highlighted, barMetrics: .Default)
```